# Calabash-android: Touch fails due to "No elements found" but element was found

Tags: java, cucumber, cucumber-jvm, calabash

I'm using [calabash-android-java](https://github.com/vishnukarthikl/calabash-android-java) to test a hybrid application built with Xamarin. As you can see below, I'm able to query for the DOM element, and even log some information to console, however when I execute the touch command, for whatever reason, the element can no longer be found.

I took a look at at the point of failure in the calabash-android-java [source code](https://github.com/vishnukarthikl/calabash-android-java/blob/master/src/com/thoughtworks/calabash/android/CalabashWrapper.java), however it just seems to pass my query off to a scripting engine, which is as far as I can take it.

Am I simply misunderstanding the use of the touch command? I would assume it should be able to "touch" an anchor tag, but perhaps not?

At any rate, any assistance would be greatly appreciated...my Google fu has failed me this day.

**HTML**

```
<div style="width: 100px">
    <a data-role="button" ng-click="submit()" id="loginButton">Log In</a>
</div>
```

**Java**

```
@When("^user \"(.*?)\" logs in with valid credentials$")
public void user_logs_in_with_valid_credentials(String username) throws Throwable {
    UIElement login = app.query("webView css:'#loginButton'").first();
    System.out.println("Element_Id=" + login.getId());
    System.out.println("Element_Class=" + login.getElementClass());
    System.out.println("Element_Query=" + login.getQuery());
    System.out.println("Element_Text=" + login.getText());
    System.out.println("Element_Enabled=" + login.isEnabled());
    Rect rect = login.getRect();
    System.out.println("Center_X=" + rect.getCenter_x());
    System.out.println("Center_Y=" + rect.getCenter_y());
    login.touch();
}
```

**Console output**

```
Element_Id=loginButton
Element_Class=ui-btn ui-btn-up-c ui-shadow ui-btn-corner-all
Element_Query=webView css:'#loginButton' index:0
Element_Text=
Element_Enabled=false
Center_X=91.98979
Center_Y=308.5714 
com.thoughtworks.calabash.android.CalabashException: Failed to touch on: webView css:'#loginButton' index:0. (RuntimeError) No elements found. Query: webView css:'#loginButton' index:0
at com.thoughtworks.calabash.android.CalabashWrapper.touch(CalabashWrapper.java:293)
at com.thoughtworks.calabash.android.UIElement.touch(UIElement.java:196)
at com.mycompany.calabash.LoginStepDefs.user_logs_in_with_valid_credentials(LoginStepDefs.java:41)
at ?.When user "xxx@xx" logs in with valid credentials(C:/_Workspace/calabash-android-java/calabash-android-java/src/test/resources/features/login.feature:13)
```

**UPDATE:** It's worth noting that I'm able to touch the element using the same query when in console mode, and the device responds accordingly:

```
irb(main):023:0> touch("webView css:'#loginButton'")
{
    "bonusInformation" => [],
             "message" => "",
             "success" => true
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I updated to clabash android 0.5.1 which helps to handle better touch and set text on webelements. Web views are now handled better(consistent with calabash android).

https://github.com/vishnukarthikl/calabash-android-java/issues/3

Answer (score 0):

After speaking with [Vishnu](https://github.com/vishnukarthikl) via [GitHub](https://github.com/vishnukarthikl/calabash-android-java), I was able to alter the source code to work around the bug:

Note, one must truncate the String "index:N" that is appended to the query variable, which is subsequently passed to the Ruby script:

**CalabashWrapper.java**

```
public void touch(String query) throws CalabashException {
    try {
        info("Touching - %s", query);
        query = query.substring(0, query.indexOf("index:"));
        container.put(QUERY_STRING, query);
        container.runScriptlet(String.format("touch(%s)", QUERY_STRING));
        pause();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        error("Failed to touch on: %s", e, query);
        throw new CalabashException(String.format("Failed to touch on: %s. %s", query, e.getMessage()));
    }

}
```